# Google Earth Engine API: How to select an image from an image collection based on NDVI value?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2

I want to select the image with lowest median NDVI to represent bare ground cover from Sentinel-2 image collection for my region of interest (<5% cloud).

I have a boundary file pre-loaded on Asset called `boundary`.

I started with:

```js
var start = ee.Date('2017-05-01'); //Dates of interest
var finish = ee.Date('2018-10-31'); 
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterBounds(boundary)
.filterDate(start, finish)
.filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5)); 
//to get imagery with cloud coverage below 5%

//compute NDVI for each image
var NDVI = sentinel.map(
    function(img) {
        return img.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
              .rename('NDVI');
    });
print(NDVI)

// now compute median for each NDVI image
var Dict = NDVI.map(
  function(img){
   return img.set('NDVI', 
    img.reduceRegion({
     reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
     geometry: boundary,
     scale: 10})
   );
   }); 
print(Dict);

var best = ee.Image(Dict.sort('NDVI').first()); 
print(best);
```

It turns out `Image (Error) Collection.first: Cannot compare values '{NDVI=0.254702177047319}' (Type<Dictionary<Object>>) and '{NDVI=0.18543783789000937}' (Type<Dictionary<Object>>).`

Ideally, I want it to return the index of that image from the `sentinel` image collection in response to the lower NDVI median so I can select it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I answer my own question:

```
var Dict = NDVI.map(function(img) {
  var median = img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), geometry:boundary, scale: 10});
  return img.set({median: median.get('NDVI')});
});

var best = ee.Image(Dict.sort('median', true).first()); 
print('Index: best image with the lowest NDVI median:', best.get('system:index'));

var bestImage = sentinel.filter(ee.Filter.equals('system:index', best.get('system:index'))); 

print('best image', bestImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute normalized difference in Google Earth Engine over an `ImageCollection` you have to `map` a function over it:

```js
var NDVI = sentinel.map(
    function(img) {
        return img.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
                  .rename('medianNDVI')
    }

// now compute median of the collection
var median_NDVI = NDVI.median()
```

Comment: Thanks, good to learn new codes. However, I think you have misunderstood my question. `print(NDVI)` gives me 22 NDVI images and `print(median_NDVI)` gives me the median NDVI layer at each pixel. But what I want is to compute the median value for each layer and then select the image with lowest NDVI, then export that original image with bands. So treat NDVI as a threshold for image selection.

Comment: I get it, I think you should edit your question (the whole question) trying to express better what you mean, and I'll edit my answer too.